# Django query with random

Tags: django

In views.py

I want to randomly choose one record with my filter:

```
a=Entry.objects.filter(first_name__contains='Br')).order_by('?')[0]
b=a.id
c=Entry.objects.filter(first_name__contains='Br')).order_by('?')[0]
d=c.id
```

It is possible that b and d are same.

But my goal is to get each time different entry object and id. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about fetching both objects in the same query? That way you know you have two distinct entries.

```
a, c = Entry.objects.filter(first_name__contains='Br')).order_by('?')[0:2]
b = a.id
d = c.id
```

Note that this will raise a `ValueError` if the filter matches fewer than two entries.